# Merge cells if value exceeds the width of the cell

Tags: vb.net, excel

I need to merge two cells if the contents or value of the cell exceeds the width of the cell.

For example, I have text that is 1000 characters, when writing it automatically wraps to the next line. I need to merge the cells so that the contents will fit into one cell.

Comment: Merging the cells is going to affect the width of the entire column that the cell is in.  Is that what you want?  What is the ideal end product here?